# Как вывести данные с массива?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

При попытке вывести список учатсников, выходит undefined. Хочу узнать у людей, как получать userID с базы данных правильно

```js
async run(message, args) {
  let toClanNName = args[0]
  let clanTable = await Clan.findOne({
    guildID: message.guild.id,
    clanName: toClanNName
  });
  
  if (!clanTable) 
    return (message.reply("Такого клана нету!"));
  const rank = clanTable.members.userRank;
  const id = clanTable.members.userID;
  
  console.log(rank, id);
  
  let embed = new MessageEmbed()
  let ow = bot.users.cache.find(u => u.id === clanTable.owner)
  embed.setTitle(`Информация о клане ${clanTable.clanName}`)
  embed.setDescription(`Описание: ${clanTable.clanBIO}`)
  embed.addField("Общее", `∙ Владелец › ${ow}\n∙ Участников › ${clanTable.members.length}/15`)
  embed.addField("Участники", `${clanTable.members.userID}`, true)
  embed.setColor("#36393E")
  message.channel.send(embed)
}
```

Данные с mongodb:

[image: Данные с mongodb:]

Answer (score 0):

Для наглядности представим массив объектов:

```js
[
  { count: 1 },
  { count: 2 },
  { count: 3 }
]
```

Допустим, мы хотим вывести `.count` первого объекта, попробуем аналогично вашему вопросу -

```js
const arr = [
  { count: 1 },
  { count: 2 },
  { count: 3 }
]

console.log(arr.count); // undefined
```

Вот так можно получить `.count` первого объекта:

```js
const arr = [
  { count: 1 },
  { count: 2 },
  { count: 3 }
]

console.log(arr[0].count); // 1
```

То-есть вы должны для начала обратиться к конкретному объекту, а только потом к его свойству.